# How to fire an event on browser resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a [jquery modal popup window](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) on my page. I would like to use resize event like below:

> $(window).resize(function () { //some code };

Everything works fine but this function is also fired when modal window is resized. I just want the code to run on browser window resize.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copy-paste error? You need to close the resize function `});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the target :

```
$(window).resize(function (e){//Pass the event
    if(e.target === window){
        //Is the window!
    }
});
```

If you resize the modal, the target will be the div itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have a working js fiddle here using jQuery 1.9.1 : http://jsfiddle.net/dwpd7b7r/

Your javascript :

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $( "body" ).prepend( "<div>" + $( window ).width() + "</div>" );
});
```